# Gremlin - get random query results after filtering

Tags: gremlin

I have the following query:

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('courseContent').
  has('status', 'active').as('cc').
  outE('ccBelongsToCourse').
  has('status', 'active').
  inV().
  hasLabel('course').
  has('externalId', ':courseId').
  select('cc').by(valueMap('externalId', 'term', 'name')).
  dedup().
  range(:offSet, :limit);
```

How can I randomize the results I get after filtering by `courseId` ? I know I can set

```
g.V().
  hasLabel('courseContent').order().by(shuffle)
```

But this will reshuffle all the results, I want to randomize only after filtering by `courseId` and only `active` nodes.
Is that possible ?

Comment: Where exactly do you want to randomize? Is it after the `dedup` ?

Comment: before the limit takes affect

Comment: So `order().by(shuffle)` after the `dedup()` ?